# Could you repeat that please?

Tags: phrases, english-to-japanese

I recently was on the phone with a Japanese customer service representative and I couldn't quite understand what she had said. I wanted her to repeat what she had said so I said something along the lines of 'again please' or 'one more time please'. What I really wanted to say was 'could you repeat that please'.

How do I say the latter in Japanese?

Comment: Related, I think: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11617/6840

Comment: The accepted answer in the link has the phrase I was looking for. Granted, in the link it is 'could you explain that again please' rather than'could you repeat that please', but this was the phrase that I thought I had heard before and the one I was after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

もう一度説明してくれますか？ is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

If you wanted to say it a little more properly:

```
すみませんが、もう一度{いちど}お願{ねが}いします。
```

This is more explicit; "Sorry but can you please say that again?". I would use this if I couldn't understand one piece of the conversation.

or

```
すみません。声{こえ}が／お電話{でんわ}が遠{とお}いようなのですが。
```

This is a soft or roundabout way of asking the other person to repeat themselves. I usually use this if the person in general is hard to understand or there is light static on the line. It would be a cue for the other person to speak up or speak more clearly.

Comment: The first phrase you mentioned is exactly what I said. I guess what I said was ok then?

Comment: For sure! I think this can be used in many situations, whether you are a customer on the phone or you are in a more business setting.

Answer (score 2):

```
もう一度言ってくれませんか？
```

...will work just fine.  If you want to go really colloquial but somewhat challenging:

```
はい？
```

Elegant, but requires the right intonation.  You have to make it sound like a question. There are other ways, such as "sorry, I couldn't hear you", or "Sorry, the signal is bad..."  Another cheat I use all the time is built on the concept of repeating everything the other side says on a business call in Japan (and adding ということですね as a suffix).  If you're in the right ballpark, just throw out something as a guess.  If you're wrong, they'll tell you again (and hopefully clearer/slower).  The caveat is that w/ customer service, they will always speak keigo which can be a nightmare for a while.

Comment: This did occur to me, but I really thought there was another phrase for it.

Answer (score 0):

To a customer rep. I would say:
すみませんが、先ほどのを聞き取れませんでした。もう一度お願いできませんか。

If I was a customer rep. talking to a customer for e.g., I might be more polite and say something like:
申し訳ございません、お電話が遠いようなのですが。もう一度お願いできませんでしょうか。